# How do I set the default location when opening files in Komodo Edit?

Tags: file, directory, komodo

I use Komodo Edit to do all of my coding.  All of my files are located in my WAMP server installation (W:/wamp/www).  It gets annoying to have to find my way to that directory every time i want to open a file.  How do I set Komodo Edit to automatically open that directory in the "File Open" screen?

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the following plugins:

- [Remote Drive Tree](http://community.activestate.com/xpi/remote-drive-tree)
- [JS Drive Tree](http://community.activestate.com/xpi/jstreedrive)

It can be set as the default path in Remote Drive Tree, or as a favorite in JS Drive Tree.